# How can i transform a JSON Value in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I want to retrieve the username of the member who publish something in Facebook with my iPhone App.
I got it but in bad format.
My code :

```
//My method
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

         NSLog(@"received response %@",response);

//The callback
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me" andDelegate:self];
```

And i got this in GDB:

```
received response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1a11e0>
```

What's the format : JSON i think but how can i transform it in a simple NSString ?

Thanks

Flo.

Comment: And by the way, you should accept answers and show your appreciation for others heling you, else no one will listen to you any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to access the response. You are using a method from the NSURLConnection delegate protocol.

You should implement the following methods as well:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

This method can be called many times, so you'd like to add the incoming data to a NSMutableData instance.

and

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

which will tell you that loading of the data has finished, your response is complete.

When the received data is complete you can create a string with it with.

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

I'd recommend a [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to parse json strings.

Comment: Thanks but what's my callback ?

Comment: @Florian_accessdev I am willing to help, however you should accept answers to your questions first...

Comment: @Florian_accessdev you should accept my answer only if it answers your question, I meant your older questions you asked here on SO. Please have a look at them, has none been answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [JSON-Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for parsing JSON.

Anyway... you should look at the [NSURLResponse Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...